# ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSchemeCombination' from 'pip._internal.exceptions'

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip

I am quite new to programming so don't be mad if I get something wrong.
I updated pip to its latest version (something like 21.x.x) and I tried to install the Detectron2 Git repo.
But anything related with pip (even when checking its version) I get the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.progress_bars import BAR_TYPES
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/progress_bars.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version, site_packages, user_site
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import _distutils, _sysconfig
  File "/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_sysconfig.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.exceptions import InvalidSchemeCombination, UserInstallationInvalid
ImportError: cannot import name 'InvalidSchemeCombination' from 'pip._internal.exceptions' (/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/exceptions.py)
```

Is there a solution for my problem?
I also tried downgrading to an earlier version but as I said any comment with pip inside gives me this Traceback...

If anyone out there can help me I would be so grateful!

Comment: I have the same problem after running some conda updates. It seems conda and pip have conflicted here. Maybe a reinstall will solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Do you mean reinstalling conda?
Because I can't reinstall pip or downgrade to another version...

Comment: yes. Albeit, I have not tried it myself. :)

Comment: Thank you very much! That helped and everything is working now :)

Answer (score 14):

I was having the same error after upgrading to pip 20.x.x, there is a solution on GitHub(https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599) which helped me to understand the problem, but it doesn't help me. So let's come to the solution

### Solution

1. Manually remove or delete the `pip` file and `pip-20.2.4-py3.7.egg-info` file from the directory, which in your case is located in `/Users/user/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages` and for some it's in `/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages`.
2. Now use `conda remove --force pip` to completely remove pip from your system.
3. Finally, use `conda install -c anaconda pip` to install pip in your anaconda environment.

For me, it worked, hope it will work for you too

best of luck

Comment: Thank you very much!
That's the way to go. You have to reinstall conda and everything works fine again.